# How do I enable double-click on the text document in RStudio?

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I'd like to double click on a variable name in RStudio. I have the latest version `Version 1.2.1335` and I'm running it on Mac OS Catalina. I'm also using R 4.0.0.

When I double click on a variable name, it sometimes selects it and sometimes does nothing. It's usually fine at the beginning of a session on RStudio, but after a couple of hours it works inconsistently.

I'm wondering if this might be a memory issue because I have a lot of data in the environment.

FWIW, my Mac has 32GB of ram.

What do you recommend to solve this?

Also- please let me know what sort of context I can share for a repro example.

Comment: Did you already try to uncheck Tools > Global options > Code > Diagnostics > Show diagnostics?

Comment: Can you tell me why that will help?

Comment: Yes sure, I had a similar issue with RStudio slowing down, and I read this related post: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-running-abnormally-slow-for-every-action-including-cleaning-console-and-saving-file/24878/3

Comment: Super interesting! Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure if it actually improves anything, so it should suffice as a comment.